# Ranking the columns by the number of missing values

Tags: r

I have a dataset with almost 9000 rows and 200 columns. Some of the data points are missing. How could I create a ranking (e.g. in a table) of variables so that they would be sorted by the number of missing entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
 sort( colSums( sapply(datfrm, is.na) ) )
```

With a functional language like R sometimes the way to think about reading code is start at the "inside" by applying the is.na function, and then "work your way out" to the final condition (sorting). If you wanted the least missing column first you would set `, decreasing = TRUE` since the default for sort is ascending.

If you wanted the columns sorted inside the dataframe (so need another extraction function from that result used to order the columns), it might be:

```
 datfrm[ , names( sort( colSums( sapply(datfrm, is.na) ) ) )]
```